# what's better pull or merge to branches on github

Tags: git, github, merge, git-pull

I have some project on GitHub, there is few branches in there.

- master
- alpha
- beta

for example. Now I create new branch `alpha-issue1`. On alpha branch was added some commits by my colleges and I want to copy this changes to my branch. First time I think `git merge alpha` would be good idea, but then I read about 'better way' - `git pull alpha test-issue1` (if I right). So I don't know what way to chose..

Comment: `git pull` is essentially just `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.  So this is asking whether it's better to run `git merge`, or to run `git merge`.  The questions to ask are not "pull vs merge" but rather "merge vs rebase, and if merge, precisely *what* to merge".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly: a `git pull` is (roughly) equivalent to `git fetch ; git merge`. If you want to, you can read up the exact behaviour in `git help pull`. So the difference between `merge` and `pull` is more about typing a few more or less commands, not about any functional difference.

Regarding the example commands you gave - no, they do not make sense.

> `git pull alpha test-issue1`

Per your question, `alpha` is a branch, not a remote, so this is syntactically incorrect (the syntax is `git pull <remote> ...`). Also, you cannot give a "target" branch with `git pull`, all merges go into the currently checked-out branch.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your question right but here are my thoughts.
If you branch off `alpha` to a new branch where you have a few commits, the standard way is to just merge that branch back to `alpha` after you are done with it. It is also a good practice to merge `alpha` onto `alpha-issue1` before merging the new branch onto `alpha` when working in a team (many commits from different devs on the same branch). That way you would have to resolve the possible conflicts on the working branch (`alpha-issue1`) instead of the main (`alpha`).
On the other hand pull is normally used when you want to update your branch with the latest commits.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on `alpha-issue1`, `git merge alpha` will replay the changes made on the `alpha` branch since it diverged from `alpha-issue1` on top of `alpha-issue1`.

---

Assuming you are on `alpha-issue1`, `git pull alpha` will pull the changes made on `alpha` branch since it diverged from `alpha-issue1` and merge it on `alpha-issue1`. As you can see, it is essentially the same.

---

In fact, the better question will be [git-merge vs git-rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge)